# How to get the duration of any video file (.avi .mp4 .flv .mkv etc) using python script (in ubuntu)?

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, ubuntu-12.04, ffprobe

I am interested in finding the duration of a video file (of commonly used formats) using a python script in UBUNTU.
I found the code:

```
def getLength(filename):
result = subprocess.Popen(["ffprobe", filename],
stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)
return [x for x in result.stdout.readlines() if "Duration" in x]
```

but it does not work on my UBUNTU BOX may be because of absence of ffprobe or something and i get the following error:

```
File "leng.py", line 8, in getLength
stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I only want the duration so is there any easier method or how to make the above code work
Is there any simple way?

Answer (score 2):

Just install ffmpeg with

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu comes with avconv by default and not ffmpeg (ffmpeg is just a wrapper for avconv).

It seems you don't have either installed.